# A word or term for a physical type of a prize?

Tags: phrases, terminology

Is there any phrase with the word "prize" that would describe that the prize is a material one? I.e. you would get some kind of a product or thing, not money.

Comment: Just the word prize is generally enough though it does depend on the setting. If I was at a fête, I would expect prizes to be non-monetary. If I was playing the lottery, I would expect the prize to be cash.

Comment: It's more often that I hear clarification for the opposite case: "Enter now, for your chance of a ***cash*** prize of £100" for example.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to find a vital translation for the Czech phrase, which is quite specific as it stresses non-monetary attribute, but it is derived from the word - materialistic/tangible. Thanks again. Non-monetary sounds the best.

Comment: It's a good idea to wait about a day before accepting an answer. Otherwise, you may discourage people from posting even better answers. (Although I agree that bib's answer is excellent.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider **[swag](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/swag?view=uk)**

> products given away free, typically for promotional purposes:
>   *check out the fun bag of swag we gave our guests!*

Since the source of non-cash prizes are often donating them to advance their products, you might also call them **promotional prizes**.

---

Be careful, swag is understood by some to be an acronym for "Stuff We All Get" - [see the first three acronym definitions](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=SWAG) implying that the physical things have *low physical worth.* if this were confused in a prize/contest context then it could send the wrong message, or reduce participation.

Also, "swag" is [used in sports](http://www.sportsswag.com) and [music venues](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/concert-swag) to indicate the things you can buy with the name of the team or band on it. The latter are not free nor a prize.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard a specific word used, but generally I see people reference whatever the top tier prize(s).

Example:

> Win a car, an Xbox 360, or a bunch of other prizes!

Answer (score 1):

How about "***non-[monetary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/monetary)***" if that is the attribute of the prize that you are most wishing to stress?

> I was hoping there would be a cash jackpot but all the prizes were non-monetary.

Comment: +1 because it fits in your example, but it seems that the OP is trying to find a fit for an advertisement and non-monetary seems "clunky" to me.

Answer (score 1):

It may sound a bit highbrow, but I think *[tangible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tangible) goods* fits the bill.

> a : capable of being perceived especially by the sense of touch : palpable

Comment: Cash is definitely tangible.

Comment: @user814064 Yes, but it's a liquid asset.

Answer (score 0):

We can call them "*non-cash prizes*".

Answer (score -1):

> Trophy

This is clearly a physical thing.  Trophies need not be non-functional.

> Souvenir

Not specifically and award, but definitely *physical*